# Most efficient way to sort a Django QuerySet based on a form value

Tags: python, django-queryset

Working on a project with another fella. This is some code I wrote in `view.py` to sort a QuerySet based on some form data:

```
# Get sort by value
sort_by = search_form.cleaned_data.get('sort_by', SORT_BY_LAST_VISIT)

# Gather stops
stops = Stops.approved_objects.filter(**query_attributes)

# Do neccessary sorting
if sort_by == SORT_BY_PRICE:
    stops = stops.order_by('price')
else: # By default, sort by last visted
    stops = stops.order_by('last_visited')
```

However, last night my colleague modified the code to this:

```
# Get sort by value
sort_by = search_form.cleaned_data.get('sort_by', SORT_BY_LAST_VISIT)

# Gather stops based on sort
if sort_by == SORT_BY_PRICE:
    stops = Stops.approved_objects.filter(**query_attributes).order_by('price')
else: # By default, sort by last visted
    stops = Stops.approved_objects.filter(**query_attributes).order_by('last_visited')
```

His SVN comment: `More efficient`.

According to [Django's documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), both will equate to one database query. It is possible that I'm missing something else. Perhaps the fact that I'm setting the stops variable (`stops = ...`) twice?

Because I cannot get a hold of him till Monday, thought I'll go to the SO community on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnecessary optimization. Besides:

```
# settings.py
SORTS = {SORT_BY_PRICE: 'price'}
DEFAULT_SORT = 'last_visited'

# whatever.py
sort_field = settings.SORTS.get(sort_by, settings.DEFAULT_SORT)

stops = Stops.approved_objects.filter(**query_attributes).order_by(sort_field)
```

That's what you should be doing ;)

Comment: +1 for improving something that I did not know needed improvement. As always, much obliged @Ignacio.

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague's solution should only save one `STORE_FAST` instruction (assuming that this is in a function. If it's global than it's a `STORE_GLOBAL`) and one `LOAD_FAST` (or `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction).

I'm pretty militant about sweating the microseconds (when I know how to) but not at the cost of readability. Your version is much more readable.

Although, I would do

```
sort_field = 'price' if sort_by == SORT_BY_PRICE else 'last_visited'
stops = Stops.approved_objects.filter(**query_attributes).order_by(sort_field)`
```

Comment: Yes this is in a view.py function. His code to me screams pre-optimization and, in my biased opinion, is less readable. I like your version (+1) but we will be adding more SORT_BY_* values in the near future. I'm assuming you won't take the same approach then, correct?

Comment: @Nimmy Absolutely correct. With more than two values, Ignacio's is absolutely the right way. For only two values, mine is (I think) just as readable and faster depending on how `==` is implemented. For more, his will be better.